# Function that takes a restricted generic type as parameter and return type

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm trying to create a function that wraps a function with either type `GetStaticProps` or `GetServerSideProps` and returns a function with that same type that wraps the function that is passed as a parameter (again, same type).

This is so that the wrapper knows exactly about what is wrapped, and I believe I could do this with generics.

How can I fix the following example? The expected result is that I can only pass a function of type GetStaticProps or GetServerSideProps and wherever this function is used TypeScript (and therefore my IDE) will know what I passed.

```
export type GetGenericProps = GetStaticProps | GetServerSideProps;

export function handleGetPagePropsErrors<T extends GetGenericProps>(
  wrappedHandler: T,
): T {
  return async (context) => {
    try {
      return await wrappedHandler(context);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof AppError) {
        return {
          props: {
            error: {
              message: err.message,
              type: err.type,
            }
          }
        };
      } else {
        throw err; // just let Next.js handle it
      }
    }
  };
}
```

And if I use this function like the following, I expect the type of `context`, and therefore the types of `req`, `res` and `params` to be known to be the same as `GetServerSideProps`s

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = handleGetPagePropsErrors(
  async ({ req, res, params }) => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      throw new AppError(
        ErrorType.BAD_THINGS_HAPPEN, 
        "Sometimes code just doesn't work, dude"
      );
    }

    return {
      props: {
        foo: 'bar'
      },
    };
  },
);
```

The `AppError` is just a simple class extending `Error` that includes the error type (from an enum)

```
class AppError extends Error {
  type: ErrorType;

  constructor(type: ErrorType, message: string) {
    super(message);
    this.type = type;
  }
}

enum ErrorType {
  BAD_THINGS_HAPPEN = 'BAD_THINGS_HAPPEN'
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite seem to be a [mcve], since it is possible that `wrappedHandler`'s return type does not include `{props: {message:...}}`, and so `handleGetPagePropErrors(wrappedHandler)` would not return a `T`. You could ignore this and use a type assertion, like [this](//tsplay.dev/N7bGnw), or refactor to be type safe but more complicated like [this](//tsplay.dev/Nd3Jkw). I'm happy to write this up as an answer but could you edit the code here with a few use cases where you actually call `handleGetPagePropErrors()`?  I want to know that what comes out of it is of the type you expect.

Comment: Actually, doing the type assertion as you said gives me the expected result. It'd be nice if the type of the returned function was known from `T` but is good enough for me.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information that might be of interest. I'm not sure how to provide more use cases, the only other use case that I might do is switch to `GetStaticProps`. 


In that case, `context`'s type inside the wrapped function should be inferred to be `GetStaticPropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery>` instead of `GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery>`.


Anyway, as I said previously, doing the type assertion works wonderfully for me.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will write up an answer.  You might also want [overloads, like this](https://tsplay.dev/N9A29N) since it doesn't have some of the weird issues that generics have.

Comment: Oooh, like Java! Didn't know that Typescript had that feature, that'll come in handy, thank you so much! If you end up writing an answer I'll gladly mark it as the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that a value is of a particular type, but the compiler is not able to verify this and complains about it, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to silence its warning.  (Sometimes the type you are asserting is so unrelated to the type the compiler expects that you have to do an intermediate type assertion.  So if `foo as Bar` doesn't work, you can always write `foo as any as Bar`.)

For your code, that would mean the following:

```
function handleGetPagePropsErrors<T extends GetGenericProps>(
  wrappedHandler: T,
): T {
  return (async (context: any) => {
    try {
      return await wrappedHandler(context);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof AppError) {
        return {
          props: {
            message: err.message,
            type: err.type,
          },
        };
      } else {
        throw err; // just let Next.js handle it
      }
    }
  }) as T; // <-- assert here
}
```

Note that by doing this, you are taking responsibility for type safety away from the compiler in this instance.  If your type assertion turns out not to be correct, then you have lied to the compiler, and you won't find out about this until you run into some runtime issues.  So be careful.

With the above, the generic type `T extends GetGenericProps` can be more *specific* than just one or the other of the union elements.  For example, typeScript lets you [set "expando" properties on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions), like this:

```
const gssp = async ({ req, res, params }: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    throw new AppError(
      ErrorType.BAD_THINGS_HAPPEN,
      "Sometimes code just doesn't work, dude"
    );
  }

  return {
    props: {
      foo: 'bar'
    },
  };
};
gssp.expandoProp = "oops";
```

So `gssp` is a `GetServerSideProps`, but it also has a `string`-valued `expandoProp` property.  Something like `GetServerSideProps & {expandoProp: string}`.  And *that* means the compiler will think that the output of `handleGetPagePropsErrors(gssp)` will *also* have such a property:

```
const getServerSideProps = handleGetPagePropsErrors(gssp);
getServerSideProps.expandoProp.toUpperCase(); // okay?!
// no error from compiler, likely error at runtime
```

But of course it won't, because your implementation of `handleGetPagePropsErrors()` does not return a value of the exact same type as the input, but a value of a related type.  Technically, `as T` was a lie.

It is quite probable that, in practice, you will not run into this sort of weird edge case.  I just want you to be aware that such issues exist, and to be careful when using type assertions.

---

Another possibility here is to do something whose types a little easier to guarantee (but still takes some of the type safety burden away from the compiler and onto yourself), and to write `hangleGetPagePropsErrors()` as an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

TypeScript lets you declare multiple distinct *call signatures* for a function, with a *single implementation* that has to work for all call signatures.  The compiler checks such implementations quite loosely, so it is still possible to lie to the compiler by returning a value of the wrong type.  At least, though, you can limit the possible output types to just `GetStaticProps` or `GetServerSideProps` and not every possible generic subtype of `GetGenericProps`.

Here's how you'd do it:

```
function handleGetPagePropsErrors(wrappedHandler: GetStaticProps): GetStaticProps;
function handleGetPagePropsErrors(wrappedHandler: GetServerSideProps): GetServerSideProps;
function handleGetPagePropsErrors(wrappedHandler: GetGenericProps): GetGenericProps {
  return (async (context: any) => {
    try {
      return await wrappedHandler(context);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof AppError) {
        return {
          props: {
            message: err.message,
            type: err.type,
          },
        };
      } else {
        throw err; // just let Next.js handle it
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And you can see that the previous issue with expando properties no longer exists; the function doesn't purport to return something more precise than just `GetServerSideProps`:

```
const getServerSideProps = handleGetPagePropsErrors(gssp);
// getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps
getServerSideProps.expandoProp.toUpperCase(); // error!
// Property 'expandoProp' does not exist on type 'GetServerSideProps'
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgcQKYwMowIY2AYwAUoIwBnAGhXQ1SgDc6NgATVY0y6zOxqZth3IBhCADsYqAB7wAvnABmJEHADkY6TFUAobfgA22MmTgBBMGACiUElETa4cfOLIwoAV3wxoACjDuAI30COBBUY2wAc1QALjhXKGAxSKp-IJCYAE8wWPi3JMiASkQ4WW0y7VQxdxVrWwAVbNR7RwAhUwARAH16gAkASQA5ZAwu3tNCQktBuABeNXbuvqGRsYmpwZ0K6UhYOCyc7jQNRKIScjnuLFwCIRMAHyveJlZ2c7IAbl0d6HgFdzEXmA4jgAAtsGIWPpUGgYIQom9OHVoGQADz1OCaKosEyw450W7vAB8PgccAA7lBsBZUCxehCoXQ4vUKNpCsyWnAoOh3FAxHAfEZMoCBc4JJo4hDMsVZkTOY43Jl5Y4uTy+XBsOTsMB4JTqTk6QzoVAfGLJDJCl8VaUnLh8KCBXQoMUEGTrcAFI6bHAkq4IfhUBBPeYrDZoC63dbVTBefzXVGo2B3nF4wmo2EItE4k6AHQZsgI1lpqMHXK50tF4ulSsJ2RWqPyVD6MjNVMJmCgkjkzE2D5wAD0-bgACt3K44ND4INNDnhyZwZDoT6YJHHGVrevSsUjHB6l9tlJdvAxePIsYwJchSKfEhuQBHKjcrhgbBUkAmWRxWG0BgvQTvURxQtOY5VTD0BQAWVwUEcypSEIBAHxijlAAGHMAFYI2tDsuzgDRuxDZETVXOAiMaHIc0WHoBmGUZxkmaYaxVAAiDAEPQUBwicCA2BHMd4BYCBwjEVRdWgABrKgWHcNhmMjS0yQqRxuRjdU2zgJNOBTEiFAgCA4lUAJXx0DdKzrcovjPMgwBzHYGQgIRLmYvTyGYr5vkPX5uLEU8aGefhXjuS4F0ZWF4WiO4iLIHwrLABToh4X8Av-ThbMPeyhBzbwAFUaSgYQjFQJC+0HOAIHE7BMgAfgAQm0UqxAgHtbEUZRuPAYBjSoYJxKbJUnWgDV4A8CRON0SpPL2f5ATwEEQuhMKEUisMoDIAAmHw9RpQ1FyZK4cDwM5OHZfabiO8gvh+KaASBOajRhdBwsRcgoo2raDXpXaoC-PykoEZ6yBO79-P+u5Lsmv4btm-l5oeuElveV7NqpbbPsZb6jiqAlzsBn6YHxU4gtTFTYwFK98FFcRzRgSUxGlEDlUVZVlLVflNW1XUUY++6TTNTQFI3W0YHtL1nWZn1PR8J0fR8nBAUDYMLCIrC0xJtSSOtTTyG0qsVXzBFsxsPNwgLaImOLUtDagLKmnNhs7bXetBabFtxYVTsIG7J0SqHUdx0nOBpxkWd53u5cSM3NdFIUg8j283zEr4UH3jW4L7sWiLEZW9aYvPBTSoSn8k8ClO8aLv8Ae0QuQZLzg1rSl94MynK8oKltioHIcBqgOrSqEOgsjUOym-OVQ4EErjGvgaRgHHEFSzUYG-tr8gdCAA)